# A question about a non-linear ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Given the equation $x''(t)+x'(t)+x^3(t)=0$ with $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=0$ how to prove that

1. $ \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } x\left( t \right) = 0 $.
2. For every $t>0$ it is $x(t)>0$.

The first question is easy. With the second question I'm stuck, at least analiticaly.This problem is from G. Gallavotti "The elements of Mechanics"